# NGINX: IP with subfolder - produces 403 error

Tags: laravel, nginx

Try to setup Laravel on http://176.99.4.205/front/.

Write the following NGINX site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/vbulash/nginx.html;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ^~ /front {
        allow all;
        alias /home/vbulash/nginx.html/front/public;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            allow all;
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/front.site.error.log;
}
```

Unfortunately, this config produces 403 error. What's wrong?

UPDATE:

Try to do the following:

```
location /front {
    alias /home/vbulash/nginx.html/front/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @front;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}

location @front {
    rewrite /front/(.*)$ /front/index.php last;
}
```

According to many advices here at stackoverflow - no luck, 403 error again (((

Comment: Look at the access log and error log.

Comment: @RichardSmith nothing interesting in access log - just 403 error without any valuable information

Comment: It may not be valuable or interesting to you, but it may help others understand how to answer your question. You should edit your question and include the entries from both log files.

Comment: 198.16.66.100 - - [21/Nov/2023:14:12:12 +0300] "GET /front/ HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5845.1077 YaBrowser/23.9.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: If there is no error log entry, then the response is probably coming from PHP and **not** Nginx. You could confirm this with `curl -I` and look for any PHP headers. Also, check any PHP error log. There are two common reasons for a 403 response from Nginx, either the `index.html` or `index.php` file is missing ("Directory index is forbidden") **or** the process running Nginx does not have read access to every directory in the path below `/home`.